# systemd error using cloudprintd

Tags: 16.04, services, systemd

I have been using google cloud print for a couple of years with no issues. Also cloudprintd continues to work for me to print from my chromebook and android devices here on my home network with no issues. However... I am trying to integrate my own shell scripting into my systemd startup and in the process I discovered this output from the standard systemd status command for the cloudprintd service...

`# systemctl status cloudprintd`

```
● cloudprintd.service - Google Cloud Print proxy service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cloudprintd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-03-06 10:40:19 CST; 4s ago
  Process: 9430 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cloudprintd -a /var/lib/cloudprintd/authfile.json (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 9430 (code=exited, status=2)

Mar 06 10:40:19 HP-Compaq-Elite-8300-SFF systemd[1]: cloudprintd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 06 10:40:19 HP-Compaq-Elite-8300-SFF systemd[1]: cloudprintd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Is this anything I should be concerned about or is this normal?

This is a 16.04 LTS lubuntu install with very few customizations.